# Old MMORPG "Erinia", still online?

Tags: erinia

ten years ago or propably even more, I was playing my first MMORPG ever, called Erinia. It wasn't available for long in Germany, so I lost track of it. But over the years I always heard some rumors that there are some servers in Brazil where you can still play the game.

I looked again today, but I can't really find a definite answer if the game is gone for good or if it is still alive.

I would love to take a look at it again. Does someone know something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erinia is online again.

There is an [active forum](http://erinia-deutschland.xobor.de) regarding the game, however it is in German.

Answer (score 3):

Doing a quick google search I was able to find this [link](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erinia_(MMORPG)). Translating it to English, the game appears to have been closed and reopened multiple times. The last section seems to indicate that the game was reopened in 2011 sometime. Although no URL is given to play the game and no other information is provided saying if the game is currently in operation.